# How can I install bitdefender antivirus?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, antivirus

Can anyone tell me how to install Bitdefender antivirus from terminal if it's possible? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to install BitDefender antivirus via the terminal. You need to first add the repository by doing

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/ bitdefender non-free"
```

Next, get and add the repository key

```
wget https://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/bd.key.asc
sudo apt-key add bd.key.asc
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install by doing

```
sudo apt-get install bitdefender-scanner-gui
```

Once BitDefender is installed you can launch it with the following command:

```
/opt/BitDefender-scanner/bin/bdgui
```

---

### Troubleshooting

If BitDefender fails or crashes when trying to update virus signatures, you can try the following steps taken from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2255454.html). One additional caveat to this answer is that you *may* need to wait at least 1 hour from your last attempt to update using the GUI. The application warns about not checking for updates again within that time frame.

```
sudo touch /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so.linux-x86_64
sudo ln -fs /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so.linux-x86_64 /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so
sudo bdscan --update
```

Now it may show 0 signatures. However, after your first scan, it will display the correct number of signatures.

Answer (score 0):

See the Ubuntu page on this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BitDefender.

It might happen that the packages repository won't be accessible for various reasons (e.g. The repository 'http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb bitdefender Release' is not signed).

The alternative is:

download and inspect http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/dists/bitdefender/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages file which would contain e.g.:

```
Package: bitdefender-scanner-gui  
Filename: pool/non-free/b/bitdefender-scanner-gui/bitdefender-scanner-gui_1.0-3_amd64.deb
```

See also Depends section, which would contain e.g.:

```
http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/pool/non-free/b/bitdefender-scanner/bitdefender-scanner_7.6-3_amd64.deb
```

Download and install (with [GDebi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gdebi.1.html)):

1. http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/pool/non-free/b/bitdefender-scanner/bitdefender-scanner_7.6-3_amd64.deb
2. http://download.bitdefender.com/repos/deb/pool/non-free/b/bitdefender-common/bitdefender-common_3.1.2-1_amd64.deb

Once the Bitdefender is installed you can launch it with the following command:

```
/opt/BitDefender-scanner/bin/bdgui
```

Comment: Unfortunately on Ubuntu 19.04 `/opt/BitDefender-scanner/bin/bdgui` will crash with `libpng warning: Application jmp_buf size changed Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.